# How to loop in ajax call using Datatables?

Tags: php, loops, datatables

I'm trying to set as `data`in my database `columns:` my own array in the Ajax call.

I need to replace those static columns in a dynamic columns (I created my own class constructor and my array is ```$myObject->tableFields````.

I just want to know how I can loop the columns (in the ajax call) to replace `usuario`, `apellido1`, `apellido2`, `email`) by `$myObject->tableFields` within a loop to loop whole array.

Do you know what Im trying to say, guys?

```
<?php
    
        get_header_admin('Alex - AlexCRUDGenerator');
        get_content_admin('Alex', 'AlexCRUDGenerator');
        
        global $DB;
        
?>

    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
<?php 
        
    class GenerateCrud {
        
        // Properties.
        
            public $tableName;
            public $id;
            public $tableFields = array();
    
        // Constructor.
        
            function __construct($tableName, $id, $tableFields){
                $this->tableName = $tableName;
                $this->id = $id;
                $this->tableFields = $tableFields;
                
                //is_string($tableName) ? $this->tableName = $tableName : $this->tableName = null;
                //is_string($id) ? $this->id = $id : $this->id = null;
                //is_string($tableFields) ? $this->tableFields= $tableFields : $this-$tableFields = null;
            }
    }
    
    $myObject = new GenerateCrud('users_test', 'id', ['usuario', 'apellido1', 'apellido2', 'email']);
    
    // Parse array to string.   
    $myStringArray = implode(",", $myObject->tableFields);
    
    $sql = "SELECT $myStringArray FROM $myObject->tableName";
    $res = $DB->get_records($sql);
    
    #################################### Generate HTML - START ####################################
    
        $buttonModal = "<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-lg-12'><button id='btnNuevo' type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal'><i class='material-icons'>library_add</i></button></div></div></div>";
        
        $html = "<table id='crudTable' class='display' style='width:100%'>";
        
            $html .= "<thead>";
                $html .= '<tr>';
                foreach ($myObject->tableFields as $ths){
                    $html .= '<th>' . $ths . '</th>';
                }
                $html .= '</tr>';
            $html .= "</thead>";
            
            $html .= "<tbody>";
                foreach ($res as $r){
                    $html .= '<tr>';
                    foreach($myObject->tableFields as $field){
                        $html .= '<td>' . $r->$field . '</td>';
                    }
                    $html .= '</tr>';
                }
            $html .= "</tbody>";
        $html .= '</table>';    
    
    #################################### Generate HTML - END ####################################
        
        echo $buttonModal . '<br>' . $html;
        
    ?>

    <!--  #################################### JAVASCRIPT START #################################### -->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var id, opcion;
            opcion = 4;

            $('#crudTable').DataTable({
                "language": {"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "searching": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "scrollX": true,

                "ajax": {
                    "url": 'main',
                    "method": 'POST',
                    "data": {opcion: opcion}
                },

                "columns": [
                    {"data": "id"},         // I want this data in a dynamic way with my own array ($myObject->tableFields).
                    {"data": "usuario"},    // I want this data in a dynamic way with my own array ($myObject->tableFields).
                    {"data": "apellido1"},  // I want this data in a dynamic way with my own array ($myObject->tableFields).
                    {"data": "apellido2"},  // I want this data in a dynamic way with my own array ($myObject->tableFields).
                    {"data": "email"},      // I want this data in a dynamic way with my own array ($myObject->tableFields).
                    {"defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button></div></div>"}
                ],
                
            });
        } );
    </script>

    <!--  #################################### JAVASCRIPT END #################################### -->
        
<?php 
        
    get_footer_admin();

?>
```

Comment: You can create array for that coloumns, by getting the tables coloumns name then make array from it like this https://3v4l.org/VDR92

Comment: Hello! I can't understand that example. ```$data``` array means the names of my database columns? And ```$theCol``` means the column with key-value (data-myColumn)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My preference is to provide that array as a separate part of the ajax response, rather than extracting it out of the data array - although that is definitely one way to do it. In my approach, the JSON response structure would change from something like this: `{ "data": [ {...}, {...} ...] }` to something like this: `{ "data": [ {...}, {...} ...], "columnMetaData": [ "col1", "col2", ... ] }`. You can even expand that to contain the table headings you want to display as well as the data IDs.

Comment: Small side note: @Caín - if you want to ping a specific person, take a look at how `@` works in comments: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). I used your user name as an example - but in this case, that was not necessary, since you get pinged for all comments, anyway, because you asked the question.

Comment: @ThomasJeriko Hello! I can't understand that example. ```$data``` array means the names of my database columns? And ```$theCol``` means the column with key-value (data-myColumn)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @andrewjames Okay, I think I got it but I don't know how to iterate and put my array inside of ```{ "data": [ {...}, {...} ...], "columnMetaData": [ "col1", "col2", ... ] }``` because I have been trying, and I can't create a loop inside of ```"columns" : []```. Thank you in advance and thank you also for that little note.

Comment: @Caín hello, the $data just the example of DB fields names (i assume you got the fields name in array form)

Comment: @ThomasJeriko Okay, but what if my DB fields name are also an array? How can iterate it inside of the ajax call?

Comment: @Cain you make the array in the PHP side, then on Javascript side you just use it as coloumn names. `"columns": dataFromPhp`